# Automation test chromium edge

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, chromium

I try to run selenium test with chromium edge version 79.0.309.56.
This is the code for the test but I got an error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unrecognized Chrome version: Edg/79.0.309.56

the code is:

> ```
> System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "<path to driver>\\msedgedriver.exe");
> ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
> chromeOptions.setBinary("<path to browser>\\msedge.exe");
> DesiredCapabilities m_capability = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
> m_capability.merge(chromeOptions);
> EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
> try{
>     RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<ip>:80/wd/hub"), m_capability);
>     driver.get("http://www.google.com");
> } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
>     e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```

I didn't find a solution for this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of selenium server and Microsoft Edge (Chromium) driver are you using? I use **selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar** and **Microsoft Edge (Chromium) driver 79.0.309.43** and the code can work well when automating Microsoft Edge (Chromium) 79.0.309.56.

How do you launch the hub and the node? You could refer to my steps below:

**Launch a hub:** using the command prompt, navigate to the path of selenium server, then type on the command prompt:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -maxSession 10 -port 4444
```

**Launch a node:** navigating to the same path and type on the command prompt:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="your\path\to\webdriver\msedgedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://<your_ip>:4444/grid/register -port 3333
```

After launching successfully, run the code you providing and the `Capabilities` will show on the command prompt like this:

```
INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
    ],
    "binary": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedge.exe",
    "extensions": [
    ]
  },
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "version": ""
}
```

*Reference: [Selenium Grid Tutorial: Hub & Node (with Example)](https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html)*